# SQL:how to find duplicated combinations in two adjacent columns

Tags: sql

I have a table (field1, field 2, field3, field4), 
 How can I sift out only those rows which contain duplicated combinations in two adjacent columns - field3 and field4? i.e ->
[image]

Comment: Sorry, just after the posting my text got formatted and lost the initial view, hope this will make it more clearcut-A

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: Please define `adjacent columns` In SQL there is no ordeing defined in rows nor columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select *
from mytable t
join (
    select field3, field4, count(*) from (
      select field3, field4 from mytable where field3 <= field4
      union all
      select field4, field3 from mytable where field3 > field4) x
    group by field3, field4
    having count(*) > 1) y
  on (t.field3 = y.field3 and t.field4 = y.field4)
    or (t.field3 = y.field4 and t.field4 = y.field3)
```

The `union all` inner query lines up all the values, without removing duplicates (as `union` does) into consistent columns - the where clauses ensure that rows aren't selected twice.

The inner query is then grouped with a `having` clause to pick the duplicates.

The outer query joins to these both ways to get all the rows.